# Linked table to presentation - what is the size limit of the source table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-workspace

I'm trying to link a table from a google sheet to a google presentation.

I'm normally presented with a dialog asking me whether I want to link the spreadsheet (meaning all changes in the source data can be seen in the presentation by the click of a button). However, once the source table reaches a certain threshold, I only get the data and no option to link it.

So the question is

**a)** does anyone know the limitation to the size of the source?

**b)** is there a way around that limitation? When I try to cheat by adjusting the range I get `Invalid range`

[image: error message]

Comment: I'm having same issue... It's sad nobody answered yet.

Comment: I agree, although think I'm lazy to not just do a simple test to check this out...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the limit is 400 cells - I haven't been able to find a way to extend it with a single link, but you can add multiple linked tables to a slide to "assemble" your sheet.

"*Tip: Tables with more than 400 cells will paste unlinked into your document. You cannot expand a previously linked table beyond 400 cells.*"

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7009814?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cadd-a-table-from-google-sheets